# Image with position absolute overflow parent hidden

Tags: css, css-position, overflow

I have this:

```
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="inner">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="./images/illustration-woman-online-mobile.svg" media="(max-width: 890px)">
          <img src="./images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg" alt="top-image">
       </picture>
       <picture>
         <source srcset="./images/bg-pattern-mobile.svg" media="(max-width: 890px)">
         <img class="sec-image" src="./images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg" alt="top-image">
       </picture>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I set the img-container with position relative and inner class with hidden overflow. Why the second image (the only one with position: absolute) still overflow my  img-container?
Maybe if I apply position absolute hidden overflow doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a working example, with any relevant CSS, thanks. As described the overflow hidden should work so there must be something else that is having an effect.

Comment: I've resolved.  was my fault. Thanks!